# How to remove an element from JSON string in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have a json as a string and I need to remove one element from it using java code. Appreciate your help.

Example.

Tried arrays and stuff but no luck.

Input: Need to remove image

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

Output:

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

Comment: Use a JSON parser, then parse the JSON text, modify the data as needed, format back to JSON text.

Comment: Use Jackson or Gson for handling JSON in java. Never try to modify string as such. it is not maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

Here comes the sample code with different popular libraries to achieve what you want as follows:

**Jackson**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, JsonNode.class);
((ObjectNode) node.get("widget")).remove("image");
System.out.println(node.toString());
```

**Gson**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement jsonObj= gson.fromJson(jsonStr, JsonElement.class);
jsonObj.getAsJsonObject().get("widget").getAsJsonObject().remove("image");
System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
```

**Jettison**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
jsonObj.getJSONObject("widget").remove("image");
System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Install and import this package:

```
import org.json.*;
```

And using the following code:

```
 try {
            String src = "{\"widget\": {\n"
                    + "    \"debug\": \"on\",\n"
                    + "    \"window\": {\n"
                    + "        \"title\": \"Sample Konfabulator Widget\",\n"
                    + "        \"name\": \"main_window\",\n"
                    + "        \"width\": 500,\n"
                    + "        \"height\": 500\n"
                    + "    },\n"
                    + "    \"image\": { \n"
                    + "        \"src\": \"Images/Sun.png\",\n"
                    + "        \"name\": \"sun1\",\n"
                    + "        \"hOffset\": 250,\n"
                    + "        \"vOffset\": 250,\n"
                    + "        \"alignment\": \"center\"\n"
                    + "    },\n"
                    + "    \"text\": {\n"
                    + "        \"data\": \"Click Here\",\n"
                    + "        \"size\": 36,\n"
                    + "        \"style\": \"bold\",\n"
                    + "        \"name\": \"text1\",\n"
                    + "        \"hOffset\": 250,\n"
                    + "        \"vOffset\": 100,\n"
                    + "        \"alignment\": \"center\",\n"
                    + "        \"onMouseUp\": \"sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;\"\n"
                    + "    }\n"
                    + "}}   ";
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(src);
            obj.getJSONObject("widget").remove("image");
            System.out.println("obj: " + obj);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this will help you guy.